# Why the async test passed, but there are some error messages displayed?

Tags: dart, dart-unittest

Dart test code:

```dart
_doSomething2(callback(int x, int y)) {
    callback(1, 2);
}

test('async test, check a function with 2 parameters', () {
    new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds:100), _doSomething2(expectAsync2((x, y) {
        expect(x, equals(1));
        expect(y, equals(2));
    })));
});
```

When I run it in Intellij-IDEA as "unittest", it passed, but there is some error message shown:

```
Testing started at PM11:08 ...
Unhandled exception:
The null object does not have a method 'call'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'call'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#1      _createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:11)
#2      _handleTimeout (timer_impl.dart:283)
#3      _handleTimeout (timer_impl.dart:292)
#4      _handleTimeout (timer_impl.dart:292)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115)

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test ends before the code inside the `new Timer()` is executed.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  test('async test, check a function with 2 parameters', () {
      var callback = expectAsync0(() {});
      new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds:100), () {
          _doSomething2((x, y) {
          expect(x, equals(1));
          expect(y, equals(2));
          callback();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

This way the test doesn't end until `callback` is called.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you already use `expectAsnyc2`. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Freewind I updated my answer. Now I tested it, and it works. The way you did it, the callback is only created after the delay but then the test may already have ended.

Comment: Thank you, it's worked now. But it's funny that I was trying the method `expectAsync2` when I write this code.

Comment: New question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460073/how-to-use-expectasync2-correctly-when-writing-dart-unittest