# How to use `expectAsync2` correctly when writing dart unittest?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-async

I was trying this method `expectAsync2`, so there was this question: [Why the async test passed, but there are some error messages displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409349/why-the-async-test-passed-but-there-are-some-error-messages-displayed)

But it seems I didn't use it correctly. Is there any good example of `expectAsync2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the referenced question `expectAsync` was just used to guard a async call so that the test doesn't end before the call of `new Timer(...)` finishes.

You can additionally add provide how often (min/max) the method has to be called to satisfy the test.
If your tested functionality calls a method with more than one parameter you use `expectAsync2)

The mistake in your referenced question was, that your call to `expectAsyncX` was delayed too.
The call to `expectAsyncX` has to be made before the async functionality is invoked to register which method has to be called.

```dart
library x;

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

class SubjectUnderTest {
  int i = 0;
  doSomething(x, y) {
    i++;
    print('$x, $y');
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {

  test('async test, check a function with 2 parameters', () {
    var sut = new SubjectUnderTest();
    var fun = expectAsync2(sut.doSomething, count: 2, max: 2, id: 'check doSomething');

    new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds:200), () {
        fun(1,2);
        expect(sut.i, greaterThan(0));
    });

    new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds:100), () {
        fun(3,4);
        expect(sut.i, greaterThan(0));
    });

  });
}
```

You can check what happens if you set `count` and `max` to `3`.

Comment: Thank you, but where can I write the `expect()` statements?

Comment: That depends what you want to expect ;-)

Comment: I extended my answer a little.

Comment: I know your idea, thank you! I will edit your answer to make it more clear:)

Comment: You have edited, and that's just what I want to know :)

Comment: Found there are some mistakes in the code, fixed it

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at the [Asynchronous tests section](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/#asynchronous-tests) of the article *Unit Testing with Dart*.

Comment: I was reading that article while I was posting this question. That article didn't give me enough information, I don't know where is wrong with my code in the related question.