# How to test asynchronous Stream in Dart

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-async

I have simple class like this

```dart
abstract class ServerConnection {
  Stream onMessage;
  Future send(Message m);
  ...
}
```

You call send with message and asynchronous response will stream to onMessage. Now i need to send through this connection various messages and test responses. I made this test, but its not working (i am lost with these expectAsynces) and _waitForNextEvent is not very nice (but at least working!)

```dart
test('connection', () {
  getCon().then((ServerConnection c) {

    Future<Message> _waitForNextEvent(Stream s) {
      StreamSubscription ss;
      Completer c = new Completer();
      ss = s.listen((Message m) {
        ss.cancel();
        c.complete(m);          
      });
      return c.future;
    }

    _waitForNextEvent(c.onMessage).then(expectAsync1(
      (m) => expect(m, new isInstanceOf<OkMessage>('OkMessage'))
    ));
    c.send(new StatusMessage());

    _waitForNextEvent(c.onMessage).then(expectAsync1(
      (m) => expect(m, new isInstanceOf<PongMessage>('PongMessage'))
    ));
    c.send(new PingMessage());
  });
});
```

So what is the right and elegant way to test Dart Streams?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use \`expectAsync2\` correctly when writing dart unittest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460073/how-to-use-expectasync2-correctly-when-writing-dart-unittest)

Comment: Take a look at the referenced question. If it doesn't help add a comment. You need to register a method that you expect to be called using `expectAsyncX()` **before** you start any async operation.

Comment: In the most recent unittest package (0.10.0) expectAsync0/1/2 are deprecated [Changelog - unittest 0.10.0](http://8.dartlang-pub.appspot.com/packages/unittest).
It seems that 0.10.0 has a bug [Unittest 0.10.0 expectAsync Failure and other problems](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16677) (just to make you aware as you might run into it).

Comment: I guess this test will always break, since both message will trigger both callback, e.g. send the `PingMessage` and the test will break because the first callback is expecting an `OkMessage` assuming `PingMessage` is not subclassing `OkMessage`. I guess the safe way to do it is to create a new stream for every different message, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Günter, async tests must be defined **before** async test itself. It is not easy to test longer async communication though.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Async is a bit difficult at the beginning but you get used to it.